# SSIS For Loop Container with Date Variable

Tags: date, for-loop, ssis, odbc

I want to create a monthly package that executes a daily query at ODBC and writes an output file.

More specifically the query must be first executed for the first day of the previous month `(e.g. '01/11/2018')` then the next one `('02/11/2018')` until the last day of the previous month `('30/11/2018')`.

The date variables are currently saved as Strings and I also want to have a string variable with Oracle date format to be inserted into the query. How should it be organised? Is there a way that I could use the string variables in the expressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Break it into parts as follows:

1. Declare variables to store previous month start and end date as follows:

**start_date(datetime)** = `(DT_DATE)((DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("MM",-1,GETDATE()))+"-"+RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(DATEADD("MM",-1,GETDATE())),2)+"-01")`

**end_date(datetime)** = `DATEADD("D", -(DAY(GETDATE())),GETDATE())`

2. Declare variable `Counter(datetime)`
3. Create a `For loop container` as follows :

[image: img]

4. Rest of the Data Flow Task should be there within For loop container, which will create output file. You can use the variable `Counter` in SQL to parameterize it

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I figured out that all I wanted to use in my loop was the daypart of the date, so I created two extra int variables that contains:
1) the first day of the month (1)
2) the last day of the month (28,30,31)
I used those two variables at the `For Loop Expressions` and convert the index to string, so I could add it in the query. Possibly there will be a better way and it would be welcome.