# SSIS For Loop - Increment 'YYYYMM' by Month in Loop

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, ssis, expression, etl

I am trying to execute a for loop that passes a begin date in the format like '201812' and goes up increments to an end date (as an example) of '201903'.  The variables get passed as Integers to stored procs which then grab and insert data based on those values.  I was trying to implement the pattern found here but it does not seem to be correctly incrementing:

[SSIS For Loop Container with Date Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591179/ssis-for-loop-container-with-date-variable)

I have set up variables as follows:

[image: User Variables]

The ETLBeginPeriod and ETLEndPeriod are set in Execute SQL Tasks here:

[image: Variables Get Set]

And then here are the expressions in the For Loop

[image: For Loop Expressions]

The full expression in the AssignExpression is

```
@[User::Counter] = LEFT((DT_WSTR,19)(DATEADD("mm",1,(DT_DBDATE)(LEFT((DT_WSTR, 10) (@[User::Counter]),4) + "-" + RIGHT((DT_WSTR, 10) (@[User::Counter]),2) + "-" + "01"))),4) + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,19)(DATEADD("mm",1,(DT_DBDATE)(LEFT((DT_WSTR, 10) (@[User::Counter]),4) + "-" + RIGHT((DT_WSTR, 10) (@[User::Counter]),2) + "-" + "01"))),6,2)
```

When testing the *AssignExpression* the expression itself does return a correct value (i.e. it will change `201808` to `201809` but this doesn't seem to be getting hit.  It will get the correct value on the initial pass and run `201808` and then try again with `201808`.  So it doesn't seem to change the Counter Value.

Comment: You have to write the solution as a separate answer, not to add it within the question

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is that you forgot to cast the whole result as integer. Try using the following expression:

```
@[User::Counter] = (DT_I4)(LEFT((DT_WSTR,19)(DATEADD("mm",1,(DT_DBDATE)(LEFT((DT_WSTR, 10) (@[User::Counter]),4) + "-" + RIGHT((DT_WSTR, 10) (@[User::Counter]),2) + "-" + "01"))),4) + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,19)(DATEADD("mm",1,(DT_DBDATE)(LEFT((DT_WSTR, 10) (@[User::Counter]),4) + "-" + RIGHT((DT_WSTR, 10) (@[User::Counter]),2) + "-" + "01"))),6,2))
```

Comment: That did not seem to be the issue.  It seems to start correctly with '201908' and then retry '201908'.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out - I decided to add a script task to view the variables and it turns out that they were incrementing correctly, but I had the wrong variable assigned to get passed to the stored procedure.  I had originally been using the ETLBeginPeriod and forgot to change it to the Counter variable.  Once I did that it worked.  Arg.